# Basis for a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that the real part is also a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ be a subspace of dimension $k$, viewing $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a complex vector space. For $v \in V$, we can take the "real part" of $v$ by just taking the real part of each entry. Then $\{\mathrm{Re}(v) \enspace \vert \enspace v \in V\}$ is a real vector space.

Is the dimension of this vector space necessarily $k$? In other words, is there a basis of $V$ such that the real part of the basis is a basis of this real vector space?

I feel like the answer must be yes, and that this should be a generic property. However, this taking real parts operation doesn't seem to have very nice properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, consider $V = \operatorname{span}(1, 1 + i)$. We compute the space directly:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Re}((x + iy)(1, 1 + i)) &= (\operatorname{Re}(x + iy),\operatorname{Re}(x - y + (x + y)i)) \\
&= (x, x - y) \\
&= x(1, 1) + y(0, -1),
\end{align*}
which yields all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.